# How to show more specific places with Android places API?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-places-api

I'm able to show markers on the map using a "type" parameter with the places API but how do I show specific markers?

For example; Let's say I display markers using the specific type parameter of "department _ stores", how would i go about only showing Walmarts?

The places API documentation lists different "types" available but doesn't explain how to show specific places based on its name. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this below code you can add various types of marker icons according to its type

```
MarkerrOoptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getMarkerIcon(type)));
        markerOptions.snippet(item.getSnippet());
        markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
        map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

/*Method to get marker */

```
private int getMarkerIcon(String type) {
        int id = 0;
        if(type == null) {
            return R.drawable.ic_restaurant_map;
        }

        switch (type) {
            case "cafe" :
                id = R.drawable.ic_cafe_map;
                break;

            case "department _ stores" :
                id = R.drawable.ic_department_store;
                break;

            case "restaurant" :
                id = R.drawable.ic_restaurant_map;
                break;

            case "bar" :
                id = R.drawable.ic_bar_map;
                break;

        }
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but how do I show only markers for specific businesses? For example. I don't want to show every department store nearby, I only want the user to see the markers for Walmart. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=YOUT_API&query=Walmart
You can use extra parameters like radius,location,types